# Converting existing react app to PWA that is using onesignal and react-app-rewired

Tags: reactjs, service-worker, onesignal

I am using react-app-rewired build and trying to convert the app to PWA. I am having the issue that it is not including service-worker in the build folder.

config-override.js

```
module.exports = (config) => {
  config.module.rules[1].oneOf.unshift({
    test: /\.wasm$/,
    type: 'javascript/auto',
    loader: 'file-loader',
  });
  return config;
};
```

public/OneSignalSDKWorker.js

```
/* eslint-disable */
importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDKWorker.js');
// importScripts('./service-worker.js');
```

public/OneSignalSDKWorker.js

```
    /* eslint-disable */
    importScripts('https://cdn.onesignal.com/sdks/OneSignalSDKWorker.js');
    // importScripts('./service-worker.js');
```

package.json

```
"build": "react-app-rewired build",
```

src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import store, { history } from './store';
import App from './components/app';
import * as ServiceWorker from './serviceWorker';



const target = document.querySelector('#root');

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
      <App />
    </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  target
);

 ServiceWorker.register();
```

Comment: Hi! a few questions. The service work that is not being included is the one from OneSignal or your normal service worker you are using to power your PWA? Also, the code provided in your question public/OneSignalSDKWorker.js looks like it was posted twice. Did you mean the OneSignalUpdaterServiceWorker.js?

Comment: hi! Thanks for responding. I want to make my app progressive which is using onesignal and its service worker. I am not using the default service worker. Now I want to integrate default service workers so my PWA can be installable. To do that I am having a challenge on how to use both service worker and use it react-app-rewired.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that PWAs require by default a service worker which is going to be the one that powers up your PWAs, the OneSignal service worker will only be used to trigger your Push Notifications.

If you are integrating OneSignal into a site with an existing service worker (like a PWA), you may have to merge service workers in order for OneSignal to work correctly. See [OneSignal Service Worker FAQ](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/onesignal-service-worker-faq) for more details.

If you are looking at the OneSignal Dashboard, it gives you the option to install the service worker from OneSignal in a different path.

[image]

Resources:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-web-push#pwa-or-multiple-service-workers

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/onesignal-service-worker-faq

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/onesignal-service-worker-faq#service-worker-migration-guide

Feel free to join our community of OneSignal developers and our discord channel.

https://onesignal.com/onesignal-developers